# when running $ rails test, get the result as below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

when running  `$ rails test`, I get the error as below, how to solve this problem?

```
/home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:14:in 'test': test_should_get_help is already defined in StaticPagesControllerTest (RuntimeError)
    from /home/nafihnafi/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in '<class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    from /home/nafihnafi/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in 'require'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in 'block in require'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in 'load_dependency'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in 'require'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in 'block in require_files'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in 'each'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in 'require_files'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:94:in 'plugin_rails_init'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:81:in 'block in init_plugins'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:79:in 'each'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:79:in 'init_plugins'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:130:in 'run'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:77:in 'run'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:63:in 'block in autorun'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /home/nafihnafi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from -e:1:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `test_should_get_help` somewhere again, when it's already been defined. Make sure it's only defined once - put the function in a private block at the end of the file like this:

```
[file end]

private

def test_should_get_help
  [blah]
end
```

If you need it in multiple files, try adding it as a helper.